# Gaps Between Primes in Arithmetic Progression

Tags: prime-numbers

I'm interested in knowing if there exists a bound (possibly similar to the one found by Baker, Harman, and Pintz) for gaps between primes in arithmetic progression given a fixed quadratic character.

For example, does there exist an $\epsilon > 0$ depending on $d$ and $m$ such that, whenever $\gcd(d,m) = 1$, $\chi$ is the quadratic character of conductor $d$, and $x$ is sufficiently large, there is a prime $p$ congruent to $a \pmod m$ such that $x < p < x + x^{1-\epsilon}$ and $\chi(p) = 1$?

Comment: What if $d=m$, and $\chi(a)=-1$?

Comment: Changed the gcd so that this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: The proof of Hoheisel's theorem (which Baker, Harman and Pintz refine to a better exponent), extends to primes in arithmetic progressions. This was first done by Heilbronn in *Uber den Primzahlsatz von Herrn Hoheisel* (Math Zeitschrift, 1933). For more recent references and further improvements you may consult pages 141 and 142 of Narkiewicz's *Rational Number Theory in the 20th Century*.

Comment: Is there any version of Heilbronn's paper that is in English?